# Memory Warning in Xcode - What does one do in didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, memory

I have asked this before but I think my question was not understood, so here goes again:

We do not handle memory anymore, since ARC does that.   We cannot even invoke memory release commands etc..   So what CAN one do programmatically at RUN TIME to address a memory warning issue if the delegate receives the memory warning notification?

I do NOT want to know how to fix my code!!!
Code cannot fix itself at run time.

Assuming I have coded correctly, BUT still receive a memory warning, what can be done ..

ie Can you give an example of what to code into the

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
          // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
     ;
}
```

method?

Comment: Usually you log it and ignore it.  (But you certainly CAN do things to release memory when you get a warning.)

Comment: On receiving memory warnings try releasing the objects in memory that are not currently in use, like images, in memory caches, view controllers not on UI. You should release them to low the memory pressure and recreate them when needed.

Comment: Hot Licks : my question was what can be done? - not, can one do anything?   I am struggling to find out exactly WHAT one can do.  I need to see some code ... like Justin so kindly provided.

Comment: gagarwal - HOW does one release the objects in memory?   Please supply some code.   Remember that one cannot use for example  "release" !! if one is using ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you still have control over memory. You're just operating at a higher abstraction level with ARC.

You can use: `object = nil` to clear a strong reference. When all strong references are cleared, the object is deallocated.

If you are familiar with manual reference counting:

```
object = nil; << ARC
```

is like this when doing your own reference counting:

```
[object release], object = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too naive, but what I do is log present values of variables so I can track down errors or what may be causing the warning.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).